# XSLT XML line feeds in variables

Tags: xml, xslt

I am not a web developer but I was forced to do XSLT.

I have a variable (var1) being passed to an XSLT template which has these values 1,2,3,4. 
I need to display this as

> 1 
>  2 
>  3 
>  4

I'm using the code below to display my values.

```
<\xsl:value-of select="var1"\>
```

How can it dynamically replace the commas with line feeds? I've tried replacing the commas with & #10; (using a program) but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `<xsl:variable name="var1" select="'1,2,3,4'"/>` then using `<xsl:value-of select="translate($var1, ',', '&#10;')"/>` should suffice. Of course only with output method text or with HTML and `<pre><xsl:value-of select="translate($var1, ',', '&#10;')"/></pre>` you would see line breaks.

Comment: THanks for the quick reply. I have an output method XML. So I'm assuming that what you've suggested will not work?

Comment: Well the translate will replace the `,` characters with line breaks with any output method but depending on how you use the transformation result or look at it, for instance in a browser, white space might be collapsed. So if you want to transform XML to XML and look at the result file in a text editor you should get and see line breaks.

Comment: I've tried doing your suggestion above but it did not work. The output XML is actually being transformed into an HTML format Email. What I got was just spaces and not line breaks.

Comment: Wha! Wait it actually did work after placing the <pre> tags, but weird thing is, my font and size also changed. I've read that it has a default Courier font. Is there any way in preserving my original font face and size?

Comment: Achieved it using CSS! Thanks for the HELP!!